# Default selected value in select with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select

I'm trying to have a default selected value with ng-selected but it doesn't works.

My code is

```
<select 
    id="department" 
    name="department" 
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="editProfilCtrl.infos.department"
    ng-change="editProfilCtrl.findCities()">
        <option 
            ng-repeat="dep in editProfilCtrl.infos.departments" 
            class="text-uppercase" 
            value="{{dep}}"
            ng-selected="{{dep.idDepartment == editProfilCtrl.infos.department}}">
            {{editProfilCtrl.infos.department}} - {{dep.idDepartment}} - {{dep.code}} - {{dep.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

In my dropdown list I have this results :

- (empty)
- 1 - 1 - Code01 - TEST1
- 1 - 2 - Code02 - TEST2
- 1 - 3 - Code03 - TEST3
- ...

You can see that editProfilCtrl.infos.department = 1. So, normally it must be selected by default. But this is the empty line which is selected :/.
Do you have an idea ?

Thanks.

Edit : the **mac gyver** "solution" :

```
<select 
    id="department" 
    name="department" 
    class="form-control"
    ng-model='editProfilCtrl.infos.department' 
    ng-change="editProfilCtrl.findCities()"
    ng-options='dep as dep.code + " - " + dep.name for dep in editProfilCtrl.infos.departments'>
</select>
```

with in my controller :

```
self.infos.selectedDepartment = editProfilFormDto.department;
self.infos.departments = editProfilFormDto.departments;
self.infos.department = self.infos.departments[self.infos.selectedDepartment - 1];
```

Comment: add  <option value="">---Please select---</option>

Comment: It doesn't works. Now, I have empty line, your line, the other line. But, it is always the empty line which is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you checked the documentation or searched on the google? based on what I know, you can't do a default value using that approach. and also there is a dedicated directive for making options efficiently.

I'm a newbie but hope I helped you with my answer.

use ngOptions
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```js
/** 
  somewhere in your controller
*/
    editProfilCtrl.infos.department = editProfilCtrl.infos.departments[0]
```

```html
  <select 
    id="department" 
    name="department" 
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="editProfilCtrl.infos.department"
    ng-change="editProfilCtrl.findCities()" ng-options="dep.idDepartment+' '+dep.code+' '+dep.name for dep in editProfilCtrl.infos.departments"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way can be to set editProfilCtrl.infos.department :

```
editProfilCtrl.infos.department = editProfilCtrl.infos.departments[0]
```

in your controller and don't use ng-selected

Comment: Always not working :/ But it works with a mix of ng-options and your solutions. See my edited post ;). Thanks